# Python, Why does csv writer put quotation marks around the values

Tags: python, list, csv

I want to save a list in a csv file. The Problem is when I want to reload the file, the values are strings.

When execute my code and then cat "file_name". The output is:

```
cat test.csv -> "[1, 2]","[3, 4]","[5, 3]"
```

my code is:

```
import csv

def save_workschedule():
    small_list = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 3]]
    c = csv.writer(open("test.csv", "w"))
    c.writerow(small_list)

save_workschedule()
```

how can I save the list without the quotation marks?

Comment: The "row" is the list you are passing, which contains those 3 sub-lists. As those 3 sub-lists are items in the row, they are converted to strings to be written, hence the wrapping in quotes.

Comment: No way around it. You're writing text to a text file. If you want the file to look like `"[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 3]]"`  when you read it back, wrap `small_list` in another list when you `writerow` `c.writerow([small_list])`

Comment: Then have you tried configuring the quoting? What output do you actually want? Should each sub list be a separate line? How should the other commas be interpreted?

Comment: I want to have the values [1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 3] in the csv file

Comment: @Vinz then you absolutely need the quotes, referred to as text qualifiers. Without them, you'll be splitting on the wrong comma's when you read that data into something else. Without know more... I suspect you may be making your task a bit harder than it needs to be... what are you trying to do overall?

Comment: You want writerows not writerow. Then each sublist becomes a csv row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks a bit like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/66377/136323) to me.

The reason for the quotation marks is that your values contain commas (one such value being `"[1, 2]"`) and therefore, the CSV writer must put them in quotes to distinguish those commas from the record separators.

One way around that would be to choose a different separator, e. g. semicolon.

But it might make more sense to save that list in a JSON file or to pickle it. So the question you need to answer is: Why CSV?

Comment: could be any file, thought the csv module would be easy to use. I started using pickle now.

Comment: @Vinz another great alternative to pickle is json. Not only is is more human readable, but it is a relatively broadly recognized standard file format. pickles are more or less entirely limited to python scripting.

Comment: @Vinz: CSV is great for storing tabular/textual data. Python objects such as lists should be stored in a format that is aware of such potentially nested structures. I prefer JSON for its readability - the resulting files can be understood by humans. They also are portable. Pickle files are binary and only usable in Python itself.